# Change background color of Angular dialog

Tags: css, angular, dialog

I'm trying to change the Dialog background
without touching the `style.css` file.

As some other answers tell, there are many ways to set the Dialog style:

**1**- This solution works for width and height but the transparent background is "ignored".

```
this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      disableClose: true,
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      panelClass: "myClass",
    });


.myClass{
  background-color: transparent !important;
  max-width: none !important;
}
```

**2**- You can also use `::ng-deep` like this:
In this case the background color gets set to transparent but all the Dialogs aquire this property and **I don't want that to happen**

```
::ng-deep mat-dialog-container {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

For what I saw the `panelClass: "myClass"` option overrides this class `cdk-overlay-pane`
Meanwhile what I need to override is `mat-dialog-container` without compromising other dialogs.

Is there a way to do that without compromising the other Dialogs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `host` in your component style-sheet, with that, you only modify the styles for that particular component:

```css
:host ::ng-deep mat-dialog-container {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

**UPDATE**

So in order to customize the material dialog, you will need to create a custom css class, and set that class within your `style.scss` file:

`style.scss`

```css
.custom-modalbox > mat-dialog-container {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

And where you have the `MatDialog` injected, use that `css` class for the `panelClass` property:

`YourComponent.ts`

```js
onOpenDialig() {
  this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
    disableClose: true,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    panelClass: 'custom-modalbox', // if you don't set this
                                   // that css class won't applied
  });
}
```

So with that, other components can use the dialog safely without affecting the look & feel if they don't use `custom-modalbox`

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work but great try

Comment: That worked perfectly and that's a great solution as well. Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ::ng-deep but this way, for example

```
::ng-deep {
  .mat-dialog-container{
    box-shadow: 0px 11px 15px -7px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 24px 38px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 9px 46px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
    background: #7e2727;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  }
 }
```

Comment: mat-dialog-container isn't a class but anyway when I try this solution the ide gets kinda mad since it "expects a semicolon"

Comment: If you check when you open mat dialog in web console elements -> Styles, you can look at the .mat-dialog-container class, in my case I use a scss file and Angular 9.