# How avoiding ::ng-deep in angular material dialog style

Tags: angular, angular-material

The only way that I succee to update  .mat-dialog-container style is by adding ::ng-deep

```
::ng-deep  .mat-dialog-container {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

as I understand it is recommended to avoid using :ng-deep.

How I can update the style without it?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Maybe this one can help you for styling dialog with Angular Material https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71593732/change-background-color-of-angular-dialog/71594069#71594069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material components makes a extensive use of cdk-over-lay. This makes that to change the .css we need use a global style (a cdk-over-lay create a div "outside of" application, press F12 to see, this is the reason no .css can "reach it"). So we need override the .css  in styles.css (a ViewEncapsulation.None make the same effect)

If we want to override all the components of same type, we can e.g.

```
 //in styles.css
.mat-dialog-container{
  background-color:red;
}
```

But what happen if we only want to change the mat-dialog of a specific component? Well, all the material component (check the docs) usually has a property called `panelClass` -in the case of dialog we indicate this property in the "config"-

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      panelClass: 'custom',
     ...
});
```

Now we can use [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and create a class like

```
//also in styles.css
.custom .mat-dialog-container{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the clear and accurate explanation

Answer (score 1):

There's an option:

1. add `ViewEncapsulation.None` to your component config object:

   ```
   @Component({
       selector: 'tase-market-movements',
       templateUrl: 'market-movements.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['market-movements.component.scss'],
       encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
   export class MarketMovementsComponent {}
   ```

and then all style rules that you write apply to all your application, which is not good.

2. wrap all your CSS inside the class, ( name it as the name of your component )

   ```
    .marketMoveementsComponent {
   // write all your css code
   }
   ```
3. add this class name to the wrapper tag in the template

   ```
   <div class="marketMoveementsComponent">
        <!--  all your html code-->
   </div>
   ```

this way your CSS code is still encapsulated from the outside, but the CSS connected to the component is encapsulated.

good luck :)

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent explanation, thanks for exposing me to the encapsulation