# In Angular 14 and Material, how can I highlight the triggering button of a menu with an active item

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, menu

In Angular Material menu, how can I highlight (e.g. change its bg color) the triggering button (i.e. with the [matMenuTriggerFor] attribute) for a menu while the menu has an menu item which is highlighted because of routerLink matching:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="animals">Animal index</button>
<mat-menu #animals="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/vertebrates" routerLinkActive="active-menu-item">Vertebrates</button>
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/invertebrates" routerLinkActive="active-menu-item">Invertebrates</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Is there any Angular directive available for this purpose or any CSS trick can do?

Comment: Rememeber you need put the class `active-menu-item` in "styles.css", see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74290068/how-avoiding-ng-deep-in-angular-material-dialog-style/74290881#74290881)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mat menu does not have any inbuild directives to achieve this, but you can use isActiveChange event to check if any of the items in the option is active

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="animals" [ngClass]="{'is-option-active': isOptionActive}">Animal index</button>
<mat-menu #animals="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/vertebrates" routerLinkActive="active-menu-item" (isActiveChange)="onRouterLinkActive($event)">Vertebrates</button>
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/invertebrates" routerLinkActive="active-menu-item" (isActiveChange)="onRouterLinkActive($event)">Invertebrates</button>
</mat-menu>
```

```css
.is-option-active {
 // add the styles for highlighting here
}
```

```js
isOptionActive = false;

constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
    if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.isOptionActive = false;
    }
  });
}

onRouterLinkActive(ev) {
  if (this.isOptionActive === false && ev === true) {
    this.isOptionActive = true;
  }
}
```